# In Hevc reference software HM 16.9 I need help for generating details of CUs, PUs and TUs

Tags: c++, hevc, h.265

For a test sequence I want to get the following information:

1. Where in the reference code and how can i get the CU depth information.
2. Where and how can I get the PU sizes and modes for a specific CTU.
3. Where and how can I get the Motion vector in formation for PUs.
4. Where and how can I get the reference frame information of the PUs and their location in reference frame?
5. Where and how can I get the information about the SKIP and Merge modes being used?
6. Where and how can I get the information about the RD cost for PUs?

I want the information for statistical analysis so all the information above should be after all the decisions of CTU are made.

First part is for obtaining a data on which I can do some analysis. After that I need to know how to make the software use my calculated values for different parameters. That is the first part of my question.

Second part of my question is where in the reference software code we can modify the above parameters?

e.g. I want to set depth of 2 for a certain CTU, how can I achieve that?
or I want to force SKIP mode for a certain PU, how can I do that?
or I want to force the software to use 2Nx2N for a certain PU, how can I do that in the software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, all decisions for a CTU are made when `m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu );` is called in TEncSlice.cpp

`pCtu` is of type `TComDataCU`, so if you have a look at TComDataCU.h, you can see all the information that is contained in the object (depth, partition size, prediction mode, information about motion vectors, etc.)

To access this information, you have the functions `getDepth()`, `getPartitionSize()`, `getPredictionMode()`, `getMvField` and so on.

Concerning the second part of your question, where to modify the above parameters depends on what you want to achieve. For example, if you modify the depth of your CTU before `m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu );` is ran, the values you have changed will be overwritten by this function...

Comment: pCtu->getPredictionMode(); gives me prediction mode
pCtu->getDepth(); gives me depth
pCtu->getPartitionSize(); gives me partition size
pCtu->getSkipFlag(); gives me skip flag
pCtu->getPic()->getPOC();gives me POC
pCtu->getCUMvField(REF_PIC_LIST_0)->getMv(i).getHor(); gives me motion vectors(horizontal component) for each ith partition
you have mentioned m_pcCuEncoder->compressCtu( pCtu ); saying that all decisions for CTU are made when its called. there is another line in code which i think encodes all CTUs. m_pcCuEncoder->encodeCtu( pCtu );
can you plz explain the diff. between the 2

Comment: For each CTU i get 256 results which means this partitio0n of 256 is of 4x4 and each partition is checked for the result. For inter prediction i could not find out the reference picture number i.e from which picture the reference is taken as final decision. For the case of inter prediction i need to find out the reference picture number so that i know from which picture the reference was made.   for the second part of my question i wanted to know where the decisions are made so that if i want to force a certain parameter i can do that there. TEncCu.cpp is the place to do that?

Comment: `compressCtu( pCtu)` is the rate-distortion optimization, that is, the encoding decisions (block structure, prediction mode, etc.) are made. If I remember correctly, `encodeCtu( pCtu )` then does entropy encoding and generates the actual bitstream.

Comment: thnx mate for your help. I am unable to find the reference frame number for a PU. help needed for that.