# How to extract motion vectors and info on frame partition in HEVC HM 16.15

Tags: codec, hevc

I am using the HEVC reference software, HM Encoder Version [16.15] (including RExt) on a [Mac OS X][GCC 4.2.1][64 bit] and would like to extract at encoder side:
1) the motion vectors for each block 
2) the frame partition information, i.e. the size and location of each block in the frame to which a motion vector refers.

Does anybody have hints on what are the variables where this info is stored for each coding unit? Thanks!

Comment: The answer [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40502892/in-hevc-reference-software-hm-16-9-i-need-help-for-generating-details-of-cus-pu) should be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is available in the `TComDataCU` class.

1) For motion information, there is the function `getCUMvField()` which returns the motion vector. It's not easy to work with it though.

Basically, to access almost any of the PU/CU level syntax elements, you need to be able to work with the **absolute index** of that PU/CU. This unique index tells you where exactly your PU/CU is located in the CTU by pointing to the up-left 4x4 block of that part. 
I rememberthat that most of the times this index is stored in the variable `uiAbsPartIdx`.

If you get to know how to work with this index, then you will be able to get the block partitioning information in the CTU level. so for 2) my suggestion is that you go to the slice level when you have a loop over CUTs (I think this is done in the `compressSlice()` function). And after the `compressCtu()` function is called for each CTU (which means that all RDO decisions have been made and the CTU partitioning is decided), you put a loop over all `uiAbsPartIdx`s of the CTU and get their width and height. For example if your CTU size is 128, then you will have 32*32=1024 unique 4x4 blocks in your CTU. The function for getting width/height of the CU corresponding to a certain `uiAbsPartIdx` is `pCtu->getWidth(uiAbsPartIdx)`.

I hope it was clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I do not get how to put a loop over all `uiAbsPartIdxs` of each CTU. In `compressSlice`, I am in the for loop
`for( UInt ctuTsAddr = startCtuTsAddr; ctuTsAddr < boundingCtuTsAddr; ++ctuTsAddr )`: how do I get the indexes of the CUs (i.e. `uiAbsPartIdx`) included in the current CTU to then use `getWidth(uiAbsPartIdx)`? Do I simply start from 0 and increment the index by one? and how do I get the total number of CUs within the CTU?

Comment: Let's say your CTU width is 64 which makes 256 units of 4x4. Then if you set `boundingCtuAddr=256`, you will be iterating on all CUs inside CTU. And for each CU, you can pass this CU index (`ctuTsAddr`) to the `getHeight` and `getWidth` functions to get size of the current CU.

Comment: But the very important point is that when your CU is larger than 4x4, this means that the CU is covered by more than one 4x4 unit and you need to be careful not to consider such CU more than once. For example if your first CU is 8x8, then `ctuTsAddr=0,1,2,3` would point to this CU and if you use `getWidth` or `getHeight` functions with these values, you will get the size 8x8 four times. I hope it was clear!

Comment: what about the position of each partition included in a given CTU? Any solution to obtain this information while iterating over each of the 256 4x4 partitions? I was able to address the point referred by @Mosen in the last comment, but now I am struggling to associate the partition position (x,y)  to its respective size

Comment: `UInt CU_width = (UInt) pCtu->getWidth(partitionIdx_);
   UInt CU_height = (UInt) pCtu->getHeight(partitionIdx_);   
   UInt cuPosX = pCtu->getCUPelX() + g_auiRasterToPelX[g_auiZscanToRaster[partitionIdx_]];
    UInt cuPosY = pCtu->getCUPelY() + g_auiRasterToPelY[g_auiZscanToRaster[partitionIdx_]];` this looks fine, with these instructions being executed for each of the "real" partitions (discarding the ones self-contained in cases of sizes > 4x4)